# creating multi dimensional varchar/text arrays in plpgsql (postgres)

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, text, plpgsql

i have some functionality i'd like to get from the server-side code into the database.

i can't figure out how to set the values of a multi-demensional varchar array in plpgsql.

here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function (my_arg integer) RETURNS text[][] AS  
$$   
DECLARE  
   my_arr varchar[][];  
   r_row RECORD;  
   counter integer:= 1;  
BEGIN  
   FOR r_row IN SELECT my_stuff1, my_stuff2 FROM my_table WHERE my_val = my_arg LOOP  
       my_arr[counter][1] := r_row.my_stuff1;
       my_arr[counter][2] := r_row.my_stuff2;
       my_arr[counter][3] := 'my_string';
   END LOOP;  
   return my_arr;
END;  
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;`
```

for the life of me, i cannot figure out how to get this to work.

any help would be great.  i am using postgres 8.1 by the way (stuck at that version).

Comment: How should your array look like? What kind of result are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,I have tested it without any problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function (my_arg integer) RETURNS text[][] AS
$$
DECLARE
   my_arr varchar[][];
   r_row RECORD;
   counter integer:= 1;
BEGIN
   FOR r_row IN SELECT my_stuff1, my_stuff2 FROM my_table WHERE my_val = my_arg LOOP
       my_arr[counter] := array[r_row.my_stuff1,r_row.my_stuff2,'my_string'];
       counter :=counter+1;
   END LOOP;
   return my_arr;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```